# No ejecutar la accion del clicked en un radiobutton para una determinada condicion

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Tengo dos radiobuttons en un panel que al hacer click en cada uno de ellos realizan una accion, el problema es que dicha acción solo se debe realizar si se da una condición previa.
He intentado buscar si existe algun metodo .Cancel() o similar que pueda usar si no se cumple la condición pero no lo encuentro, de tal forma que siempre que hace click, se marca el radiobutton como checked.
Agradeceria que alguien me dijera como puedo hacer para que al hacer click en el check de un radiobutton primero haga la comprobacion que necesito y en funcion del resultado de la misma pueda hacer un .Cancel() o similar que haga como si nunca se hubiese checkeado.
Un saludo

Answer (score 0):

La forma de realiazar este tipo de operación no es violentar el mechanismo de operación del `RadioButton`, sino controlar su estado de habilitación/deshabilitación utilizando su propiedad `Enabled`.

Puedes crear un método que actualice el estado de `Enabled` de los controles de acuerdo con el estado del resto de elementos. Por ejemplo:

```
private void UpdateEnabledStates()
{
    _RadioButton1.Enabled = textbox1.Text.Equals("Esto es un simple ejemplo de comprobación");
}
```

Luego haces que cada vez que se modifique el estado de los controles que afectan la operación de tu `RadioButton` se lance un evento, y en esos eventos invocas a tu método `UpdateEnabledStates()`. En el ejemplo anterior, podrías configurar `textbox1` de modo que tenga asignado el evento `TextChanged`. Pero es sólo un ejemplo, a modo de simplificación de las cosas.

Si aún así quieres violentar el funcionamiento del `RadioButton`, entonces tendrás que procesar su evento `CheckedChanged` y reasignar ahí su estado, pero tendrás que tener en cuenta más cosas para evitar un lazo infinito, ya si modificas el estado mientras estás en la función, esto a su vez provocará nuevamente que se invoque el evento, se llame la función y... etc.